# Magento custom attribute default value not showing in front end

Tags: magento, default-value, custom-attributes

I have added some custom attributes to the products in the admin section of our Magento  1.3.2.1 installation and I've given some of those attributes default values. The problem is that the default values aren't being returned when I try to get the attribute from the product object as follows:

```
$_product->getCode()
```

Logically, I would imagine that the default value gets returned if there isn't one stored against the product, but this doesn't seem to be the case (unless I'm plainly missing something).

The list below is all the current settings for one of the attributes that isn't returning the default value set.

Attribute Properties:

> Attribute Code: code
>
> Scope: Store View
>
> Catalog Input Type for Store Owner: Text Field
>
> Default value: value
>
> Unique Value: No
>
> Values Required: No
>
> Input Validation for Store Owner: None
>
> Apply To: All Product Types

Frontend Properties:

> Use in quick search: No
>
> Use in advanced search: No
>
> Comparable on Front-end: No
>
> Use In Layered Navigation: No
>
> Use In Search Results Layered Navigation: No
>
> Use for Price Rule Conditions: No
>
> Position: 0
>
> Allow HTML-tags on Front-end: Yes
>
> Visible on Product View Page on Front-end: Yes
>
> Used in product listing: Yes
>
> Used for sorting in product listing: No

Thanks for your help!
Remy

Answer (score 1):

```
echo $_product->getMyAttribute()

echo $_product->getAnotherCustomAttribute()
For  eg Attribute Label : Short Description
Then you must write code like     
echo $_product->getShortDescription()
if Attribute Label : Weight Then
echo $_product->getWeight()


echo $_product->getAttributeText('attribute_code') 
For  eg Attribute Label : Size and Attribute Code : size Then
echo $_product->getAttributeText('size')
```

Answer (score 0):

It seams that the `Mage_Core_Model_Abstract` class will not check for attributes in the `__get` magic method.  Try using the getData method instead:

```
$_product->getData('code');
```